# Changing divs to ulist

Tags: css, list, html

I haven't worked with ulist yes, and as I know it's very important and useful thing, at the moment i have 3 divs which looks like this:

```
    <div style="clear: both;  margin:0 auto; text-align: center; width:100px; background-color:#58794c; color: #ffffff; font-size : 28px; border-top:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;" title="Shipping information">Postage</div>
    <div style="margin:0 auto; text-align: center; width:100px; background-color:#558b40; color: #ffffff; font-size : 28px; border-top:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;" title="Return information">Return</div>
    <div style=" margin:0 auto; text-align: center; width:100px; background-color:#66ac4a; color: #ffffff; font-size : 28px; border-top:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;" title="Payment information">Payment</div>
```

[image]

How could I transform them to ulist that they would look like this? Or maybe its not posible?
[image]

Comment: Please, paste your HTML and CSS separately!

Comment: there is divs codes with css inside (style=) in the post, Im not posible to edit css using .css sheets, because in this project I wont be able to edit things which is inside <head> tag.

Comment: Yes, but for the sake of the question here, it'd be much easier for us if readability of your code wasn't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` to get the li aligned horizontally.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Postage</li>
  <li>Return</li>
  <li>Payment</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li{display:inline-block; 
  clear: both;  
  margin:0 auto; 
  text-align: center; width:100px; 
  background-color:#58794c; color: #ffffff; 
  font-size : 28px; 
  border-top:1px dotted #015811; 
  border-left:1px dotted #015811; 
  border-right:1px dotted #015811;}
ul li:nth-child(1){background-color:#58794c;  }
ul li:nth-child(2){background-color:#558b40; }
ul li:nth-child(3){background-color:#66ac4a;  }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HMcr7/7/)**

Comment: Note that if you set them to inline than paddings and heights won't work.

Comment: @easwee change it to inline-block in that case

Answer (score 2):

Reset all styles from `ul` and float `li` s to the left:

html

```
<ul>
<li class="c1">Postage</li>
<li class="c2">Return</li>
<li class="c3">Payment</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul {height:30px;line-height:30px;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
ul li {float:left;display:block;height:30px;margin:0;padding:0 5px;color: #ffffff; font-size : 28px; border-top:1px dotted #015811; border-left:1px dotted #015811; border-right:1px dotted #015811;}
ul li.c1 {background:green;}
ul li.c2 {background:red;}
ul li.c3 {background:blue;}
```

Added sample with inline css: http://jsfiddle.net/JBXSz/